# How to calculate value based on cell row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to do some calculation in Excel.

```
       A       B
1      0       1
2      1       0
3      0       4
4      0       3 
5      0       2 
6      0       1 
7      1       0
8      0       2
9      0       1
10     1       0
```

The cell in column B is `the row number of cell A if it is 1` - `current cell row number`. How to set up this formula if there are many `1` in column A? (After `1` in column A the formula should reset I believe)

Comment: You mean in B2=2 if A2=1 or  0 if A2=0?

Comment: I mean, until the next `1` in column A, the formula should be `the row number which has value of 1 in column A` - `current row number`

Comment: A2 has 1, so B1 = row(A2)-row(B1) until row(B2) which is row(A2) = 1. The formula then reset. The next `1` in column A is on A7, then row(A7) - row(B3) so on until row(A7) - row(B7) which result is 0. then the formula reset again until find the next `1` in column A. Is this possible?

Comment: I updated the formula to correspond your comment kindly try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row number for A=1 in B1 use:

```
 =IF(MIN(IF(A1:$A$10=1,ROW(A1:$A$10),999999))>ROW($A$10),ROW(),MIN(IF(A1:$A$10=1,ROW(A1:$A$10),999999)))-ROW()
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Change A10 to correspond the last row of your Data and keep $ for fixed references and drag it down.
  After copying and pasting the formula double click in it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
    A   B
    0   1 =IF(MIN(IF(A1:$A$10=1,ROW(A1:$A$10),999999))>ROW($A$10),ROW(),MIN(IF(A1:$A$10=1,ROW(A1:$A$10),999999)))-ROW()
    1   0
    0   4
    0   3
    0   2
    0   1
    1   0
    0   0
    0   0
    0   0
```

Comment: after implementing this formula in my current data, all the result is 0. The value in column B is should be != 0 until the row in column A which value is `1`

Comment: by the way what is `999999` ??

Comment: please array formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter and replace $A$10 with the last references, 999999 just a number > row(A10) last row in your Data

Comment: oops, I forget to press ctrl + shift +enter . Thank you it's working.